Basic window design / Unable to connect values from different functions
The idea was to create a simple window with two buttons ("show" and "quit"), where after pressing "show" button, the textbox should perform an element from the dictionary. The program is designed with the help of "guilib" module and must include two functions "def printout" (printing a test text in the textbox) and "def main" (for constructing a window and connecting some element with the 1st functions). Both without parameters.
This one was working when everything was under "if name == "main":" (def printout and content of the main function but not being a func itself (without def main)).
I am messed up and I can't get the idea how should I connect "printbox" between two functions, as current code results"NameError: name 'printbox' is not defined". Moreover, changing the payload in dictionary is also possible, so even "None" as a pair for "textbox" in dict is also possible. And again it causes an error.
Thank you in advance!!
Program to fix:
import guilib

options = {
    "textbox": "Read!"
}


def printout():

    message = options["textbox"]
    guilib.write_to_textbox(printbox, message, clear=True)


def main():
    window = guilib.create_window("test window")
    leftframe = guilib.create_frame(window, guilib.LEFT)
    rightframe = guilib.create_frame(window, guilib.LEFT)
    buttonframe = guilib.create_frame(leftframe, guilib.RIGHT)
    printbox = guilib.create_textbox(rightframe, 60, 20)
    tbutton = guilib.create_button(buttonframe, "show", printout)
    qbutton = guilib.create_button(buttonframe, "quit", quit)
    guilib.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Functions from guilib:
def create_window(title):
global window
window = tk.Tk()
window.wm_title(title)
return window

def create_frame(host, side=LEFT):
frame = tk.Frame(host)
frame.pack(side=side, anchor="n")
return frame

def create_button(frame, label, handler):
button = tk.Button(frame, text=label, command=handler)
button.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
return button

def create_textbox(frame, width, height):
boxframe = create_frame(frame, tk.TOP)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(boxframe)
box = tk.Text(boxframe, height=height, width=width, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
box.configure(state="disabled")
box.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
scrollbar.configure(command=box.yview)
return box

def write_to_textbox(box, content, clear=False):
box.configure(state="normal")
if clear:
    try:
        box.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    except tk.TclError:
        pass
box.insert(tk.INSERT, content + "\n")
box.configure(state="disabled")

ONLY THESE FUNCTIONS SHOULD BE USED
And the code must include TWO FUNCTIONS as mentioned above
